# Automatic transmission move forward when shifted into neutral and reverse

Tags: isuzu

Why automatic transmission move forward when shifted into neutral and even in reverse? What probably reasons why is it happening? Can I do something for it?

Comment: What model and year car?

Comment: Is the car facing down a slope?